# Switching UIViews without changing the top bar

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I'm new to ios programming and I can't figure this out. I have a view-based application with a navigation bar and a "custom" bar under the navigation bar (An image with two UIButtons on it). Under this two bars I have two UIViews that must be shown at the press of the corresponding button on the "custom" bar, but the top bars must remain the same the whole time.

Do you have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Do you want both view to share the screen or do you want them to take up the whole screen when the corresponding button is pressed ?

Comment: I want them both to take up the screen between the bottom end and the bottom of the custom bar, but one view at a time, so if you tap the first button you see the first view and if you tap the second button you see the second view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add both the views to your viewControllers subview and use the hidden property of the views to show/hide the correct view.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 [self.view addSubview:view1];
 [self.view addSubview:view2];
 view1.hidden=YES;
 view2.hidden=YES;
}
-(IBAction) btn1Pressed
{
  view1.hidden=NO;
  view2.hidden=YES;
}

-(IBAction) btn2Pressed
{
  view1.hidden=YES;
  view2.hidden=NO;
}
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know about the hidden property....I'm going use it and see how it goes, thanks a lot!